# Background color change Java

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jframe

I tried to program about mouselistener. I wanted to make program that if mouse cursor enter or exit frame, the frame's background color change.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class EnterExitListener extends JFrame
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      JFrame frame=new JFrame();
      final int FRAME_WIDTH=500;
      final int FRAME_HEIGHT=600;
      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);   

      class MouseEnterExitListener implements MouseListener
      {
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
      {
         System.out.println("ENTER");
         frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      }
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
         {
         System.out.println("EXIT");
         frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }  
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {} 
      }

      MouseListener listener = new MouseEnterExitListener();
      frame.addMouseListener(listener);   
   }
}
```

compiling has no problem, and if I run the program, it shows ENTER, EXIT on I/O message. However, the problem is color is not changing. It's just white frame at all.

Comment: Why are you extending JFrame? Your code creates a JFrame, so there is no need to extend JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the area where the contents of the JFrame is being displayed is actually the "content pane", and not contents of the JFrame itself.

you will have to use

> frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

Comment: isn't that green check mark answered mark?? sorry I don't know about this site yet.